# VSCode API TreeView not getting children of elements

Tags: visual-studio-code, treeview, vscode-extensions

In providing a treeview to VSCode, it seems to get all the parent elements but fail to get the children of these parent elements, I've added a debug point into it and saw that it was only ever called with `undefined`, is there something improper with my implementation?

```js
export class GalleryTreeItem extends vscode.TreeItem {
  constructor(
    private extensionUri: vscode.Uri,
    public collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState,
    public readonly name: string,
    public readonly project?: Project
  ) {
    super(name, collapsibleState);
    if (this.project) {
      this.contextValue = "gallery";
      this.description = `v${this.project.config.userContentVersion}`;
      this.tooltip = this.project.config.repositoryUrl;
      this.command = {
        title: "Plywood Gallery: Open a gallery webview.",
        command: "plywood-gallery.Open",
        arguments: [this.label],
      };
      this.iconPath = vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        this.extensionUri,
        "assets/photo-gallery.png"
      );
    } else {
      this.contextValue = "chapter";
    }
  }

  getChapters() {
    if (this.project) {
      return Object.keys(this.project.parameters).map(
        (name) =>
          new GalleryTreeItem(
            this.extensionUri,
            vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.Collapsed,
            name
          )
      );
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
}

export class InstalledGalleriesExplorerProvider
  implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<GalleryTreeItem>
{
  constructor(private extensionUri: vscode.Uri) {}

  private _onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.EventEmitter<
    GalleryTreeItem | undefined | void
  > = new vscode.EventEmitter<GalleryTreeItem | undefined | void>();
  readonly onDidChangeTreeData: vscode.Event<
    GalleryTreeItem | undefined | void
  > = this._onDidChangeTreeData.event;

  getTreeItem(element: GalleryTreeItem): vscode.TreeItem {
    return element;
  }

  refresh(): void {
    this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire();
  }

  async getChildren(element?: GalleryTreeItem): Promise<GalleryTreeItem[]> {
    if (element) {
      return Promise.resolve(element.getChapters());
    } else {
      return getLocalProjects(this.extensionUri).then((projects) =>
        projects.map(
          (prj) =>
            new GalleryTreeItem(
              this.extensionUri,
              vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None,
              prj.config.projectName,
              prj
            )
        )
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I am seeing it right you are creating `GalleryTreeItem`s which are your parent nodes, but they have `vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None` which means they act like they are leaf nodes.  What if you change that to `vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.Collapsed` and then is `getChildren` called with one of those nodes when you open that node (uncollapse it)?  You do intend for the `getLocalProjects()` to produce parent nodes whise children are provided by `element.getChapters()`?  As that is how it looks you have written it.

Comment: You're absolutely right mark, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the exact passage of interest here: [TreeView guide: Tree Data Provider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view#tree-data-provider) which is a good resource for anyone building TeeViews.

> Leaving the `collapsibleState` as its **default** of
> `TreeItemCollapsibleState.None` indicates that the tree item has no
> children. `getChildren` will not be called for tree items with a
> `collapsibleState` of `TreeItemCollapsibleState.None`.

Emphasis added, the default is `TreeItemCollapsibleState.None` so if you do not explicitly set the state to something else, the children of those nodes will never be retrieved.

As I mentioned in the comments you gave your parent nodes a `vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None` property.  Apparently, vscode is smart enough to not bother looking for children of such nodes - as they can't be opened anyway.

The solution is simply to choose another `collapsibleState` like `TreeItemCollapsibleState.Collapsed` or `TreeItemCollapsibleState.Expanded`.

Answer (score 0):

"If I am seeing it right you are creating GalleryTreeItems which are your parent nodes, but they have `vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None` which means they act like they are leaf nodes."

Changing it to `vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.Collapsed` fixes it.